# How to animate image when it touches another image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one blue square and it is draggable. If it touches red box and released the blue box comes back to it's previous position. What i need is when this blue image touches the red box and released then Heart symbol should appear on the blue box and slowly increase it's size and disappears. To drag and release i am using jQuery. The only thing i need is heart symbol animation. Thank u. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madhu72kumar/46CtD/)

```
 //jquery
//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js
//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js
    $( "#draggable1" ).draggable({ revert: true });
```

[image]

Comment: How is the heart implemented? Is it an SVG?

Comment: @DavidNguyen it's png

Comment: Have you made an effort to do this yourself?

Comment: pls chk now for fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on the [Draggable events](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events) and implement a `stop` function. To implement the animation, read up on the [jQuery `animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function. The `animate` documentation even includes examples of changing sizes and opacity.

Comment: It would be nice to add an example to your answer.  I would do it, except I don't do much animation ;)

Comment: The OP seems like he doesn't know where to start. Rather than implement it for him, I'm just trying to give him the knowledge he needs to attempt a solution. I would rather that he tries something and we help correct *his* code.

Comment: So if you've read that info, what have you tried to animate the heart? What have you tried as an implementation of your `stop` method? Show us those things in your jsFiddle and we can help correct anything that isn't behaving correctly.